# How can I connect Matlab with Visual Studio for real-time data exchange?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab, real-time, mex

I'm working on a project for a real-time communication between my computer and an external server. The communication between my computer and the server works well. I send a request from my C++ - code to the server and get a response in C++.

The problems are the sending of the matlab data to the C++ - code and the evaluation of the server data in Matlab/Simulink. For that I have to transfer data in real-time between Matlab/Simulink and a C++ project in Visual Studio. I felt that I have read the whole internet in the last days, but I didn't find a perfect answer for my problem.

Here are some solutions that could work:

1. Creating a mex-File in Matlab and save it in a specific folder. Then let my C++ - Code search for new file in this folder and get the data from the file. After the response of the server the C++ - Code should create a new mex-File and save it in an other specific folder. Meanwhile Matlab would search for a new file and would load it into the workspace. 
   I don't think that this would provide a real-time data transfer, but maybe works quite well.
2. Creating a TCP/IP-Connection between Matlab and Visual Studio to exchange data directly. 
   I have no clue, whether it is even possible nor I know how to write a socket.

I hope, that someone may have some experience with my problem and could help me to find the best way to handle it. I'm thankful for every answer!

I'm using Matlab/Simulink R2017a and Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise on Windows 10.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Visual Studio does not run code, compiles code. AFAIK there is no such thing as "real time visual studio C++ code". Also it seems that you do not know what a MATLAB executable(mex) file is. A mex file is a compiled C++ code that contains the MATLAB API, so you can call it from MATLAB. You seem to be missing the basic concepts of these technologies, you may need to go back, properly understand what they do, as both of your possible solutions seem to propose non-logical things. Please do not take ofense on this coments, I am just triying to help you get help

Comment: At first: thank you for your help! Is there a file type for the data exchange between Matlab and Visual Studio? I tried .txt and .csv, but got a error.

Comment: If you trued txt and csv and you got an error that doesnt mean it can not be done, it means you did it wrong

Comment: agree with @AnderBiguri, Make a schema of your architecture. And C++ program (executable) compiled and built with the Visual Studio IDE don*t need to be run on the IDE, this is not Matlab script that need Matlab solution to be run...

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequent requirement for me,  and I use your second option, sockets for real-time communication.  Below is a function I wrote for real-time display of signal data.  Although some code in the original function has been elided, it should give you a good idea of how to use TCP sockets in Matlab to read real-time data.  My requirements are to be able to read multi-channel audio in real-time,  and the function below performs well enough for this on my desktop machine.

```
function [ sig ] = liveplot( host, port, signal_info, Fs, window_size_secs )
%LIVEPLOT Plot live data from the signal processing engine
%   The signal processing engine will send out data as a multiplexed stream
%   of N double-precision values.
%   The 'signal_info' argument should be a logical matrix of length N, where N is the
%   number of channels that are being multiplexed.  if signal_info(K) is
%   true, then that channel will be plotted.
MAX_SESSION_TIME_SECS = 60;
FRAMES_PER_SESSION = MAX_SESSION_TIME_SECS * Fs;
FRAMES_PER_WINDOW = window_size_secs * Fs;
REFRESH_TIME_SECS = 0.05;
SAMPLE_DURATION=1/Fs;
N = length(signal_info);
FRAME_SZ = N * 8; % sizeof(double)
conn = tcpip(host, port);
conn.InputBufferSize = 1024 * FRAME_SZ;
conn.BytesAvailableFcnCount = conn.InputBufferSize;
conn.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte';
conn.BytesAvailableFcn = @bytesavailablecallback;
conn.readAsyncMode = 'continuous';
seconds_read = 0;

asyncread_tic = tic;
%   bytesavailablecallback(conn);

% time window: incremented buy SAMPLE_DURATION each frame
num_frames = 0;

%Set up Plot

% plot objects, one for  each N stream in frame
h = figure;
hold on                            %hold on makes sure all of the channels are plotted


% Start the async read thread
fopen(conn);

last_refresh = tic;
while ishandle(h) %Loop when Plot is Active will run until plot is closed

   try 
    %        if (toc(last_refresh) > REFRESH_TIME_SECS)
    if (seconds_read < window_size_secs)
        seconds_read = window_size_secs;
    end
    xlim([seconds_read-window_size_secs seconds_read]);

    %            refreshdata(h, 'caller');
    % fprintf('Refresh took %f seconds.\n', toc(last_refresh));
    drawnow limitrate
    last_refresh = tic;
   catch ME
       break
   end
    %        end
end
fclose(conn);
delete(conn);

    function bytesavailablecallback(conn, ~)

        % initiate another read immediately to fill the buffer
        %         readasync(conn, conn.InputBufferSize-conn.BytesAvailable);

        n_frames_available = floor(conn.BytesAvailable / (N * 8));
        if (n_frames_available > 0)
            [frames_read, nread] = fread(conn, N * n_frames_available, 'double');
            num_frames_read = nread / N;
            if (num_frames_read ~= n_frames_available)
                throw(MException('assert',sprintf('%d frames expected, but %d read',n_frames_available,num_frames_read )));
            end
            % need the following line when only partial read - fread fails to
            % reshape the return value if nread < FRAMES_PER_READ
            sig(:, 1+num_frames:num_frames+num_frames_read) = reshape(frames_read, N, []);
            num_frames = num_frames + num_frames_read;
            seconds_read = num_frames * SAMPLE_DURATION;

            for i=1:N
                ph = plots(i);
                if (ph ~= 0)
                    set(ph, 'Ydata', sig(i,:));
                end
            end
            async_read_time = toc(asyncread_tic);
            asyncread_tic = tic;
            fprintf('Read %d frames in %f seconds, rate is %d fps\n', num_frames_read, async_read_time, round(num_frames_read / async_read_time));

        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take my time to understand the code and try to edit it for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you review the advice in the MATLAB help topic: MATLAB->Advanced Software Development -> External Programming Interfaces

This essentially gives you three options for calling C/C++ code:

- calling functions in MEX files (Help topic: Call Mex-Files)
- connecting to a COM or ActiveX server (Help topic: COM interface)
- calling functions in a .dll (Help topic: C Shared Libraries)

Over the years I have used the last two options.

The real hassle when using MATLAB to drive communications comes when you need callbacks and events.  This is because general-purpose MATLAB code all runs in the Event Dispatch Tread of Java Swing.

---

MATLAB also gives you the option to work the other way: you can call MATLAB functions from other languages.  See the the help topic:

- Application Programming Interfaces to MATLAB: Write programs in other languages, for example C/C++ and Fortran, to interface with MATLAB functionality

As it happens, I have never used this.

---

I can not advise on whether the Parallel Processing Toolbox is helpful in dealing with asynchronous communications.  Neither can I advise on using sockets, pipes, HTTP or the like.

---

I wish you success with your project.

Comment: Thank you very much, Richard! It should be possible to use COM or the .dll with two computers, shouldn't it?